# eye tracking driven vitual computer mouse using OpenCV python lkdemo

Tags: opencv

I am a beginner in OpenCV programming. Now I'm trying to develop an eye tracking driven virtual computer mouse using OpenCV python version of lkdemo. I have a code in python lkdemo. I compiled it using `python pgmname.py`.Then I have the following results.

```
OpenCV Python version of lkdemo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 64, in <module>
    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture (device)
NameError: name 'cvCreateCameraCapture' is not defined.
```

Can anyone help to solve this?

**Update:**
now the error is:

```
OpenCV Python version of lkdemo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    import cv
ImportError: No module named cv
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The API changed a while ago. Depending on your version, it should rather be something like:

```
import cv
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

what is your version OpenCV?
this example for version 2.4.5:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
c = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _,f = c.read()
    cv2.imshow('e2',f)
    if cv2.waitKey(5)==27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```